# function in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Let us assume that:

- `@RowStr` is a input
- `@wordstr` is a string.... I have collected arabic letters

Now my goal is to check the Rowstr data with this wordstr.

Ex: pubby

Each letter has to check in wordstr.  If any of the letter will match to word str I will declare as the input data was in Arabic language.  Can any one please check my function give me a suggestions?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Checking_Arabic_English]
(
– Add the parameters for the function here
@RowStr nvarchar(1000)

)
RETURNS Char
AS
BEGIN

declare @WordStr varchar
set WordStr = "ضصثقفغعهخحجدشسيبلاتنمكطئءؤرلاىةوزظذًٌَُلإإٍِلأأْلآآ؟ـ؛،٬"

declare @WordCount int
declare @index int

set @index =0
set @WordCount = 0

while CHARINDEX(@WordStr, @RowStr,@index)>0
begin

SET @index = CHARINDEX(@WordStr,@RowStr,@index)
SET @WordCount = @WordCount + 1
if @index =0
break
else
SET @index = @index + 1
end

if  @WordCount = 0

return = 'E'
else
return = 'A'

END
```

Comment: Is it your goal to get that all characters in @RowStr are in your whitelist @WordStr, or simply test for the existence of English characters?

Comment: yes campbell ... first get all the characters from @rowstr then i need to check with each character and have to compare with @wordstr...so that i can update the string whether in english or arabic by based on wordcount return value if its o mns it was in english else itz Arabic

Comment: @pubby: you've described your implementation :) What about the business requirement: is it necessary to whitelist the valid characters, or can you blacklist the English/Latin alphabet?

Comment: @ camp >> my requirement is i m having two tables with single column one is temp table and other one is main table we dont know data which can comes in which language if any data is enters in temp data table then i need to pass that string to this above function have to compare with that given Arabic if any of the letter was matched with that means then i vill declare as the particular string as an Arabic or english

Comment: I wouldn't declare `@WordStr` as `varchar` - I'd declare it as `nvarchar(60)`, and prefix the literal string with an `N` also.

Comment: @damien right now i m working on Campbell given snippet in that if i send Arabic characters means it was considering as a question mark in sql

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation, if it suits your requirements.

- assuming that regular punctuation is OK, we'll blacklist any Latin character.
- this function checks each character in the given string. If its ASCII value is in the range of A-Z or a-z, i.e. a Latin character, then it tilts,
- A `1` is returned when a Latin char is found; `0` is returned when no Latin char is found.
- a few `print` there remaining for you to test out as you need, as an adhoc script.
- this doesn't necessarily mean that the string is Arabic; just that it's non-Latin/English.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ContainsEnglishCharacters]
(
    @RowStr nvarchar(1000)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN

    declare @index int;
    SELECT @index = 0;
    declare @thisChar nchar(1);
    while(@index <= LEN(@RowStr))
    begin
         SELECT @thisChar = SUBSTRING(@RowStr,@index,1);
--      print @index
--      print ASCII(@thisChar)
        if (ASCII(@thisChar) BETWEEN 65 and 90 
            OR ASCII(@thisChar) BETWEEN 97 and 122 )
            begin
                SELECT @index=-1;
                BREAK;
            end
        else
            SELECT @index=@index+1;
    end
--  print @index
--  print LEN(@rowStr)
    if (@index =-1)     
        RETURN 1;  --print 'found a latin char!'
    else
        RETURN 0;   --print 'no latin found!'
END
```

Comment: @campbell how do you know that for English Ascii value was in between 65-90 and 97-122 similarly can we know for Arabic ..?? any idea so that i can replace Ascii values of Arabic ...!!

Comment: @campbell thank you ... your idea was almost worked ..!! but while executing if i send arabic character know then it was considering as Question mark '?'

Comment: @pubby: I've corrected my answer to define @thisChar as `nchar`.

Comment: @pubby: sounds like you'd now like to *whitelist* your Arabic chars. That's a decent idea. Try values 165-253. There are some values in that range that aren't strictly Arabic, but you can modify slightly. http://www.ascii.ca/cp864.htm